# Passing data from Ajax to ApiController

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am having issues in Asp.Net Core with trying to pass data in the Ajax call into the parameter of the API Controller function.

I am using the data field in the Ajax call to pass the value of "id". In the API controller this value should be assigned to the "id" parameter, but never is.

```
// Ajax call
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/apicomment/GetPostComments",
    type: "GET",
    data: { 'id' : 2 },
    dataType: "json",
}).done(function (data) {
    // Some function
}).fail(function (handleError) {
    // Some function
});
```

The API controller is a normal scaffolded API Controller where I get specific comments with the id parameter. But every time I make a call I get the value 0.

```
// API Controller
[HttpGet("{id}")]
[Route("GetPostComments")]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Comment>>> GetSpecificComment(int id)
{
      var comment = await _context.Comment.Where(c => c.PostId == id).ToListAsync();
      if (comment == null)
      {
         return NotFound();
      }

      return comment;
}
```

Have tried many different things, but I can't quite figure it out.

Would love any feedback that might help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also pass via query string :

1. Comment out `data` line :

   ```
   // Ajax call
   $.ajax({
       url: "/api/apicomment/GetPostComments",
       type: "GET",
       data: { 'id' : 2 },

   }).done(function (data) {
       // Some function
   }).fail(function (handleError) {
       // Some function
   });
   ```
2. use `FromQuery` to get parameter :

   ```
   public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Comment>>> GetSpecificComment([FromQuery]int id)
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Few thing to try

First about your API url it should be like this

```
url: "/api/GetPostComments"
```

It would be much cleaner

Second your data should be like this

```
data: { id : 2 }
```

Finally you cant mix up between these 2

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
[Route("GetPostComments")]
```

It should be like this

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class SomeController : ControllerBase {

  [HttpGet("GetPostComments/{id}")]
  public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Comment>>> GetSpecificComment(int id)
  {
      var comment = await _context.Comment.Where(c => c.PostId == id).ToListAsync();
      if (comment == null)
      {
         return NotFound();
      }

      return comment;
 }

}
```

So your url should be something like this api/your-controller/GetPostComments/1

You can read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: Sorry, was not able to make it work. A thing to note which I should have said is that  I don't want the url to change when fetching the comments for the post. I just want to get the data and use it in the post.